# Merging 2 tables into a table with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables that I need to merge into a different table with some expectation. See image

```
// Table 1
create table evaluation (
    [year] varchar(4) not null,
    quarterly  varchar (15) not null,
    indikator  varchar (20) not null,
    subindikator  varchar (100) not null,
    tipe varchar (10) not null,
    [status] varchar(10) not null
);

// Table 2
create table person (
    idNumber varchar(20) not null,
    [name] varchar(20) not null,
    gender char(1) not null
);

// Table 3 Merged From Table 1 and Table 2
create table detail (
    idNumber varchar(20) not null,
    [year] varchar(4) not null,
    quarterly  varchar (15) not null,
    indikator  varchar (20) not null,
    subindikator  varchar (100) not null,
);
```

Evaluation table:

[image: Table evaluation]

Person Table:

[image: Table person]

Expected Results:

[image: Table detail what i expected]

Comment: what you are looking for is cross join

Comment: check this out https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-cross-join/

Comment: thank you kind sir, will update if i found the solution

Comment: Your question would get less downvotes when you had read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)   Posting data as TEXT is more useful then throwing screen dumps, and some textual explanation on how to do the merge might be usefull (Like: "What to do with the field `[status]`, does it play any role in this question?" )

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: No need to call anyone "sir" on this site - we are all equals here.

Answer (score 0):

With a cross-join the SELECT statement would look like:

```
SELECT t1.idNumber, 
   t2.[year],
   t2.quarterly,
   t2.indikator,
   t2.subindikator
FROM evaluation, person;
```

Putting that into an INSERT statement to load your merged table:

```
INSERT INTO merged
SELECT t1.idNumber, 
   t2.[year],
   t2.quarterly,
   t2.indikator,
   t2.subindikator
FROM evaluation, person
```

Instead of that comma between `evaluation` and `person` tables in the FROM clause you can also use the `CROSS JOIN` keyword like `FROM evaluaation CROSS JOIN person`.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to combine two tables together is using the keywords UNION or UNION ALL. These two methods pile one lot of selected data on top of the other.

```
SELECT 
    name_column_one, 
    name_column_three
FROM
    name_of_table_one

UNION

SELECT
    name_column_one, 
    name_column_three
FROM
    name_of_table_two
;
```

The difference between the two keywords is that UNION only takes distinct values, but UNION ALL keeps all of the values selected. Both are used with the same syntax.

```
SELECT 
    name_column_one, 
    name_column_three
FROM
    name_of_table_one

UNION ALL

SELECT
    name_column_one, 
    name_column_three
FROM
    name_of_table_two
;
```

Comment: Thats clearly not what OP is asking for though. And when mentioning UNION vs UNION ALL you should mention that the performance of UNION is poor compared to UNION ALL.